# "Operation not permitted" on program start

Tags: macos

I am trying to run the YGOPro game on my Mac. However, whenever I try to run it, I get:

```
server:Ygopro Ingwie$ ./ygopro.app/Contents/MacOS/ygopro 
-bash: ./ygopro.app/Contents/MacOS/ygopro: Operation not permitted
```

I know there have been previous questions - none solved it. I unlocked the binary file already, tried commands like

```
chflags nouchg ...
```

But they did not do a thing.

What could I do?